# How to best represent multiple status in different columns

Tags: tables, tags, status, column

As I'm using chips component to diplay status or tags, it becomes hard and tricky to dissociate each status.

Here you can see different parameters. And status as the main value like (active or inactive), open or close.

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to best present multiple statuses in a table?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/124396/how-to-best-present-multiple-statuses-in-a-table)

Comment: I think the issue is you're using descriptions that *look like chips*, but they're not. **Chips are meant to be interactive, not descriptive.** Thus, the solution to your issue is as simple as to stop making them with a look they shouldn't have and that's it. (you could and probably should use a **badge** for the status column)